# How do I find the ABI/JSON Interface for an ETH/ERC20 contract?

Tags: erc-20, contract-invocation

I sent TUSD to my Bittrex holdings to trade for other coins, but it never went into my account with Bittrex. They claim that I sent it to the wrong address. I am trying to recover these tokens so that I don't become homeless again, but as a novice, am finding this to be extremely difficult. I am presently trying to send these same ETH/ERC20 tokens back to my Nano Ledger X via MyEtherWallet.com, but I need the ABI/JSONInterface and don't know where to find that. I am not including the TXID or the EtherScan.io URL here because, as a novice, I don't know if that is a security risk. Thank you in advance for any help that you may be able to provide.

Comment: You can get the TUSD ABI from Etherscan https://etherscan.io/address/0x8dd5fbce2f6a956c3022ba3663759011dd51e73e#code.

Answer (score 6):

The ERC-20 is a public standard which means contracts all have to support the identical ABI. You'll find the ERC-20 ABI on many places online, e.g., https://ethereumdev.io/abi-for-erc20-contract-on-ethereum/.

As a general rule, if you want to communicate with a contract that does not follow any standards, you will need the ABI from the creator of the contract somehow. Verified contracts on Etherscan provide the ABI under the 'Contract' tab.

> I am not including the TXID or the EtherScan.io URL here because, as a novice, I don't know if that is a security risk.

That's all public information and not a security risk.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just found it before finding your response, following these steps, (for anyone else reading this thread):

Comment: Thank you very much Markus! I just found it before finding your response, following these steps provided to me by a coder, (for the benefit of anyone else reading this thread): 1. click on etherscan link (etherscan.io) Thank you also Markus, for letting me know that sharing the URL for the "report" at EtherScan.io is not a security risk.
2. click on hypertext link under the "To:" row.
3. in the new page, click on the "Contract" tab which has a little green checkmark
4. scroll down and you will see a section titled "Contract ABI" with abi underneath

Comment: While the TXID is "public information", the connection to the asker's SO account is not. Might not be much of a security risk, but certainly a privacy risk.